# Group by event label and use aggregative function for secondary dimension for Google Analytics report

Tags: google-analytics, pivot, analytics

I have a list of events submitted to Google Analytics from an app.
Each event has a timestamp and belongs to a certain category.

1. category = "products"
2. event labels = "apple", "orange", "grapefruit"
3. raw event data comes with date time stamp (out of the box):

> - products -> grapefruit -> 2015-04-01
> - products -> apple      -> 2015-04-01
> - products -> orange     -> 2015-04-02
> - products -> apple      -> 2015-04-02
> - products -> grapefruit -> 2015-04-02
> - products -> apple      -> 2015-04-02
> - products -> apple      -> 2015-04-02
> - products -> grapefruit -> 2015-04-03

what I need is the aggregated report with ability to group by product and specify an aggregate function for date (for example MAX):

> - orange     -> 2015-04-02
> - apple      -> 2015-04-02
> - grapefruit -> 2015-04-03

I was able to build a pivotal report with products and dates but unable to group that by product. How can I achieve this goal?